# How to get backup of workflow in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow

I want to get a backup of my old workflow how can I do in SharePoint designer 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To Backup your workflow :**
You have Two option.

1. Save as Template.
2. Export to Visio.

**Regarding first option Save As Template.**

- from the above ribbon click on

[image]

- An informational dialog box appears to let you know the template has been saved to the Site Assets library.

**To restore from Save As Template**

- Go to asset library.

[image]

- Click Export File

[image]

- Go to your site > Click Site Actions and select Site Settings. > In the Web Design Galleries section >  click Solutions.
- Upload your exported WSP file > Activate it.
- Go back to Site Actions group, click Manage site features. > activate its feature.

[image]

For more details check [Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj819316.aspx)

**Regarding Second option Export to visio.**

If you have Visio,from SharePoint designer ,  Try to export your workflow to Visio by following the mentioned steps below :

- Open SharePoint Designer.
- click on your completed List Workflow.
- Click on “Save” and “Publish” for the completed List Workflow.
- Next, click on “`Export to Visio`”. Save the file as `CompletedWorkflow.vwi` or any preferred name.

**To restore it to the another site/farm :**

- create a new “similar” list on the current site or on a new site collection.
- click on this new list and then click on “List Workflow” to create a new workflow for this new list.
- Please make sure that you do not add any workflow steps!
- Click on “Save” and “Publish” for this empty List Workflow.
- Then, click on “Export to Visio” and save this as EmptyWorkflow.vwi or any preferred name.
- Rename both the vwi files by adding “.zip” extension. The files should be CompletedWorkflow.vwi.zip and EmptyWorkflow.vwi.zip.
- The objective is to replace the “workflow.xoml.wfconfig.xml” file from the EmptyWorkflow.vwi.zip into the CompletedWorkflow.vwi.zip.
- It is likely that you cannot replace it directly. Copy the file out to the desktop and then copy the file into the other zipped folder.
- Remove the “.zip” extension from the CompletedWorkflow.vwi.
- With this, we have a working importable Visio List Workflow.
- Back in the SharePoint Designer , close all the workflow tabs.
- Click on the “Import from Visio” and select the CompletedWorkflow.vwi.

For more details check [Ref](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wkng/2012/08/21/exporting-and-importing-sharepoint-designer-2010-list-workflow/)

Answer (score 2):

If this is designer workflow then, only have **Save as Template** and access / use it from the Assets Library.
Hope this would help you!!