# Move list to subsite with workflows and custom actions

Tags: list, workflow, sub-site, move, custom-action

I have a **list** that has some **workflows** and **custom actions**. I want to move it to the **sub-site**.

Is it possible to move it with all it's workflows and custom actions?

Answer (score 0):

As a short answer it's **not** possible where [`Export-SPWeb`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx) command doesn't export workflows

You should [`Import-SPWeb`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428322.aspx) lists first in your destination then backup and restore the workflow as the following.

You have Two option.

1. Save as Template.
2. Export to Visio.

Check the details steps at [How to get backup of workflow in share point 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191145/how-to-get-backup-of-workflow-in-share-point-2013/191168#191168)

Also, If you are working on the same farm

- in source site, Open workflow via Sharepoint Designer > select all Action and condition> copy.
- create a new workflow at your destination > paste the copied steps.